# JobIntentService not calling onHandleWork

Tags: android, intentservice, android-jobscheduler

I'm new to Services and decided to use a JobIntentService because my app has to support API 21+ but when I start my service on API 28+ it's not working properly.

I've found out that `onHandleWork` isn't called when I start my service with `Contextcompat.startForegroundService()`

My code:

**My Activity**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        intent.putExtra("fileTitle", popup.name);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,intent);
```

**My Service**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MyLog(this, "SERVICE ONCREATE", "SERVICE");
        createNotificationChannel();
        initNotification();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this subject, this is how I manage to make it work:

**My Activity**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("fileTitle", popup.name);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,intent);
```

**My Service**

```java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Init for Notification Channel in API 26+ && init notification to display
    createNotificationChannel();
    initNotification();
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    if(intent!= null && isPostorEqualOS(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)){
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nBuilder.build());
    }
}
```